# Filtering data in a text file in bash

Tags: bash, awk

I am trying to filter the data in a text file. There are 2 fields in the text file. The first one is text while 2nd one has 3 parts seperated by _. The first part in the second file is date in yyyyMMdd format and the next 2 are string:

```
xyz  yyyyMMdd_abc_lmn
```

Now I want to filter the lines in the file based on the date in the second field. I have come up with the following awk command but it doesn't seems to work as it is outputting the entire file definitely I am missing something.

Awk command:

```
awk -F'\t' -v ldate='20140101' '{cdate=substr($2, 1, 8); if( cdate <= ldate) {print $1'\t\t'$2}}' label
```

Comment: Your fields probably aren't tab-separated, or there's 2 tabs between the first 2 fields instead of 1 (suspected because of your output format). Change `$1'\t\t'$2` to `$1"\t\t"$2` then post a few lines of sample input, expected output, and the actual output you see when running your command.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Try:**

```
awk -v ldate='20140101' '{split($2,fld,/_/); if(fld[1]<=ldate) print $1,$2}' file
```

**Note:**

- We are using `split` function which basically splits the field based on `regex` provided as the third element and stores the fields in the array defined as second element.
- You don't need to set `-F'\t` unless your input file is `tab-delimited`. The default value of `FS` is space, so defining it to `tab` might throw it off in interpreting `$2`.
- To output with two tabs you can set the `OFS` variable like:

  ```
  awk -F'\t' -v OFS='\t\t' -v ldate='20140101' '{split($2,fld,/_/); if(fld[1]<=ldate) print $1,$2}' file
  ```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
awk -v ldate='20140101' 'substr($NF,1,8) <= ldate' label
```